# Showing Files as Directories in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to have one directory in which every file within can be accessed as if its a directory (from a user, URL point of view). For example, if I have:

```
users.php
admin.php
otherpage.php
```

I'd like a user to be able to type `http://mysite.com/users/` to get `users.php`

I've heard this can be done, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you change your links so that they look like: `http://mysite.com/users/` (note the trailing slash at the end), then you'd need this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

To prevent direct accesses to those php files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```